# extjs 4 : button on click event can't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

```
{
xtype: 'button',
id : 'btnShowImage',
text : 'Show Image On List',
scale   : 'large',
width : 200,
margin : '0 0 0 180',   
}

var ShowImgBtn = Ext.get('btnShowImage');
    ShowImgBtn.on('click', function(){
    alert('hi');
    });
```

### Question

how come can't work?what is the problem?should be can work.

Comment: try `Ext.getCmp('btnShowImage')` instead of `Ext.get`

Comment: thanks @MMT, Ext.getCmp('btnShowImage') is work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        id : 'btnShowImage',
        text : 'Show Image On List',
        scale   : 'large',
        width : 200,
        margin : '0 0 0 180'
    });

    var ShowImgBtn = Ext.get('btnShowImage');
    ShowImgBtn.on('click', function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/ht4UL/**

Can be your button is not rendered?

Answer (score 0):

After editing the code to

```
Ext.getCmp('btnShowImage')
```

this is working.